# Need to find number of comments on most commented post: SQL

Tags: sql, max

I have two tables and i need to find the number of comments on a most commented post.
[image]

I can get all post ordered with a number of comments but I want to add that to subquery.

My code at the moment:

```
SELECT TOP 1 p.PostID, COUNT(*) AS num_comments
FROM Comment p
GROUP BY p.PostID
ORDER BY num_comments DESC
```

But then I have a one column with PostID as well and I don't want to put that on table below.
How can i get only the value of mostCommentsPerPost ?

[image]

Sorry If i dont explain my problem well enough, this is my first post.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want `PostID`, just leave it out. You're not required to `SELECT` a column just because you're grouping on it.

Comment: That worked! I tried it before without selecting postID but I think i deleted GROUP BY as well and just got a total number of comments and I thought that I can't get it without a PostID. Thanks a lot for helping me with my silly question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just take out p.PostID from `SELECT`

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) AS num_comments
FROM Comment p
GROUP BY p.PostID
ORDER BY num_comments DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```sql
SELECT sq.postId, sq.Cnt
FROM (
    SELECT PostId, count(*) AS Cnt
    FROM Comment
    GROUP BY PostId
) AS sq
ORDER BY sq.Cnt DESC
LIMIT 1
```